# A commutative diagram of (co)homology module with relative cap products

Tags: algebraic-topology

Fix a class $a\in H_{p+q}(X,A)$. Then I want to show that the diagram
$$ H^p(X,A) \rightarrow H^p(X)$$
$$ \downarrow a \cap\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\downarrow a \cap$$
$$ H_q(X) \rightarrow H_q (X,A)$$
is commutative(where $a \cap$ means cap product with $a$).

Here I am working with singular homology and singular cohomology.

I know that relative cap products
$$ H_{p+q}(X,A) \times H^p(X,A) \rightarrow H_q(X),$$
$$ H_{p+q}(X,A) \times H^p(X) \rightarrow H_q(X,A)$$
are well defined. How to proceed with the proof?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Which cohomology are you working with?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I am working with singular cohomology.

Comment: Well I dont know your exact definition but most are based of the Eilenberg-Zilber map and it commutes with the boundary operator.